# Reset browser cache of a production create-react-app application

Tags: amazon-s3, create-react-app, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

So currently I have a react application hosted on Amazon S3 and it is served via a Cloudfront CDN however, every new production release I make, the end users have to deep refresh (`ctrl+shift+r`) the entire page (since the contents of the prev build remain in the browser cache). Is there any I could invalidate both the CDN Cache and the Browser cache only when making a production release. I use **GitLab** ci btw.

Answer (score 0):

we are using AwsPublish plugin in gulp.
Here's the code for gulp file

```
const day = 86400;
  const farFuture = { 'Cache-Control': `max-age=${day * 365}` };
  const future = { 'Cache-Control': `max-age=${day * 7}` };
  const noCache = { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' };
  const gzipTypes = '**/*.{html,css,js,svg,ico,json,txt,wasm,map,mem}';
  const cacheBustedTypes = '**/*.{css,js,gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp,ttf,woff,woff2,wasm}';
  const cachedTypes = '**/*.{ico}';
  const noCacheTypes = '**/*.{html,json,xml,txt}';
  const otherTypes = ['**/*', `!${cacheBustedTypes}`, `!${cachedTypes}`, `!${noCacheTypes}`];

  const publisher = $.awspublish.create(awsSettings);

  const options = {
    force,
  };

  return gulp
    .src(source, { base })
    .pipe($.if(gzipTypes, $.awspublish.gzip()))
    .pipe($.if(cacheBustedTypes, publisher.publish(farFuture, options)))
    .pipe($.if(cachedTypes, publisher.publish(future, options)))
    .pipe($.if(noCacheTypes, publisher.publish(noCache, options)))
    .pipe($.if(otherTypes, publisher.publish(null, options)))
    .pipe($.if(sync, publisher.sync()))
    .pipe($.awspublish.reporter());
});
```

Add index.html in noCacheTypes types. Webpack would generate chunkhash for css and js files and upon changing them the cache would be busted.
We're using github actions along with this gulp script.